# Mocking functions used inside spark udfs

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, mockito, user-defined-functions

I had a user defined function as follows:

```
def myFunc(df: DataFrame, column_name: String, func:(String)=>String = myFunc) = {
    val my_udf = udf{ (columnValue: String) => func(columnValue) }
    df.withColumn("newColumn", my_udf(df(column_name)))
}
```

Now, while writing test cases, I wanted to mock myFunc. I'm using Mockito for testing.
So I created a mock function with

```
var fmock = mock[(String)=>String]
when(fmock(any[String])).thenReturn("default_string_write_value")
```

However, when I try to pass fmock, I get the following exception: `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

So I tried to make fmock serializable by declaring it as follows:

```
var fmock = mock[(String)=>String](Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
```

Now when I call a collect on the dataframe returned by myFunc, I get the following exception:

```scala
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

This error is obtained when I am trying to perform the collect operation.

Also, a weird thing is happening. The test case passes in IntelliJ (that's the IDE I'm using), but fails when I run it with Maven.

The test case is as follows (assume I already have a dataframe-`TESTDF` in place with columns-`COL1`,`COL2`,`COL3`):

```scala
val fmock = mock[(String)=>String](Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
when(fmock(any[String])).thenReturn("default_string_write_value")

val ansDf = myFunc(TESTDF, COL1, fmock)
var rowValueArray = ansDf.select("newColumn").collect.map(x => x(0).asInstanceOf[String])

assert(rowValueArray(0)=="default_string_write_value")
```

Note that I'm using Spark versions 2.3.3 and scala 2.11.8. The application is running fine, the issue only comes in with test cases (that too on maven).